# Is it safe to mix UNICODE and non-UNICODE translation units?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unicode, one-definition-rule

I'm integrating a library which requires `_UNICODE` and `UNICODE` to be defined; I can't set these definitions globally on my project for now, so I was wondering if I can safely build only the library code with these definitions.

I'm worried about ODR violations, but as far as I understand these definitions only impact *macro* definitions in the Windows and C runtime headers, so I would expect no ODR violations (as long as my own headers shared between translation units don't depend on `UNICODE`), but is it really a guarantee?

Is it safe to mix translation units built with and without `UNICODE`/`_UNICODE`?

In other words, is it safe to compile these two files into the same binary:

```
// a.cpp
#define _UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#include <tchar.h>
// maybe other windows header inclusion
// some code
```

---

```
// b.cpp
//#define _UNICODE
//#define UNICODE
#include <tchar.h>
// maybe other windows header inclusion
// some other code
```

Comment: For information, the library maintainers are refactoring their code to make it independent of the `UNICODE` macros, but this may take some time (and the question remains interesting anyway).

Comment: To me, the question condenses to: Is there any effect of `_UNICODE` or `UNICODE` to the headers of the library? Because, this is what the compiler considers when the other code uses the library.

Comment: *"only impact macro definitions"* Don't you (or library) use those MACROs? `inline` functions are the most risky for ODR in that concern.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes the implementation of the library relies on those macros, through the use of `_TEXT()` and `xxx()` that forwards to `xxxW`. I know that the code in the library headers does not depend on these macros, but I'm not sure about Microsoft headers, hence my question. If Microsoft headers define a symbol with one definition when `_UNICODE` is set and with another definition when `UNICODE` is not set, then I'm in trouble.

Comment: If there is one inline function with `_TEXT()`/`TCHAR`/... one with preprocessor defined and one not (even if function is not used), then you got ODR violation. So "is it safe?" No. Do you have currently ODR violations? Not sure, maybe, maybe not. Can Microsoft change `<tchar.h>` or other windows headers in a way it might produce ODR violation for your code? Yes. Would they do it? Maybe, maybe not. Currently that [tchar.h](https://home.cs.colorado.edu/~main/cs1300-old/include/tchar.h) only `#define`/`typedef` some aliases. so doesn't do ODR-violation by itself.

Comment: @Jarod42 Ah this is an interesting comment and link: I thought everything was handled through macros but I see that there is indeed some typedefs. As far as I know, having two typedefs with diverging definitions _is_ an ODR violation, so the simple inclusion of `<tchar.h>` would generate ODR violations.

Comment: *"having two typedefs with diverging definitions is an ODR violation"* Not from what I understand from [ODR](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule) and [`typedef`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef). (it might lead to UB if used in inline function though).

Comment: Thanks once again for the links @Jarod42, this is all the info I needed to make an informed decision! If you feel like gathering these comments into an answer I'll happily upvote and accept it.

Comment: is it "safe" from a language perspective... yes. Is it safe from a windows API documentation recommendation perspective *Absolutely not*.

Comment: Looks like there is an intention to allow this, but still undocumented; and SDK might have  bugs that cause this intention fail for some cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is one inline function with `_TEXT()`/`TCHAR`/... in different translation unit, one with preprocessor defined and one not (even if function is not used), then you got [ODR](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule)-violation.

> "is it safe?"

No.

> Do you have currently ODR violations?

Not sure, maybe, maybe not.

Currently that [tchar.h](https://home.cs.colorado.edu/%7Emain/cs1300-old/include/tchar.h) only `#define`/`typedef` some aliases. so doesn't do ODR-violation by itself.

> Can Microsoft change <tchar.h> or other windows headers in a way it might produce ODR violation for your code?

Yes.

> Would they do it?

Maybe, maybe not.